# How to Fix Error: Could not find method deleteAllActions() for arguments [] on task

Tags: android, build, build.gradle

I have added a new library. But I don't know why I am not able to build the project.

i am getting 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':mavenirmeeting'.

  > org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method deleteAllActions() for arguments [] on task ':mavenirmeeting:extractDebugAnnotations' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExtractAnnotations.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Build Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    android {
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Google libraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    // other libraries
    implementation 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1'
}
```

What is going wrong I don't know. I am using Android studio version 3.4.

gradle weapper

```
#Tue Jul 02 13:27:58 IST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **RetroLambda** in your project and **Java8**, then please remove retrolambda in gradle.properties file.

**Java8** support lambda experession.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support?utm_source=android-studio

*Regards*